# Rasterise shapefile as 1 band (grayscale)

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, band

My code converts shapefiles to rasters. 
I had first done this in colour, but now I need greyscale (1 band). 
The code seems to create this for the first raster file, but the other raster files seem to have no bands (previously they all had 3).

```
shapefiles = [folder + '/' + file for file in os.listdir(folder) if 'shp' in file]
output = 'output'
if not os.path.exists(output):
    os.mkdir(output)
RefImage = ref_image
gdalformat = 'GTiff'
datatype = gdal.GDT_Byte
burnVal = 1 #value for the output image pixels

# Get projection info from reference image
RasImage = gdal.Open(RefImage, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

for Shapefile in shapefiles:
    ds = ogr.Open(Shapefile)
    ds_layer = ds.GetLayer()
# convert a shapefile to raster
def convertShpToRaster(inputfile, band, size):
    shp = ogr.Open(inputfile)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer(0)
    lyrname = lyr.GetName()
    #color = plt.gray()

    subprocess.call('gdal_rasterize -ts {0} {1} -l {2} -burn {3} ./{4} ./{5}.tif' \
                .format(size[0], size[1], lyrname, band, inputfile, output + '/' + lyrname))

def inputToShapefile():
    # input color, resolution and shapefile location
    #color = plt.gray()
    band = RasImage.GetRasterBand(1)
    size = RasImage.RasterXSize, RasImage.RasterYSize

    # call the function
    for inputfile in shapefiles:
        convertShpToRaster(inputfile, band, size)   

inputToShapefile()
```

Can somebody advise? Should I rasterise as before and then drop bands instead?

I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: `band = RasImage.GetRasterBand(1)` is going to set `band` to an object, but then you're passing that object into the string formatting when building the command.  Just pass a "1" as a string or an int instead.  Also note that the python bindings have an [entry point to the rasterize utility](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Rasterize) so you could avoid using a subprocess if you feel so inclined

Comment: thanks Vince. I think I have it now - adding .GetBand() to the band object and then removing band from the string part of the command, so:     subprocess.call('gdal_rasterize -ts {0} {1} -l {0} -burn 1 ./{2} ./{3}.tif' \
                .format(size, lyrname, inputfile, output + '/' + lyrname))

def inputToShapefile():
    # input color, resolution and shapefile location
    #color = plt.gray()
    band = RasImage.GetRasterBand(1).GetBand()